# How to properly create objects from a JSON dictionary that start with a numbers instead of strings?

Tags: json, swift

I'm having a tough time creating objects from the JSON below. It's weirdly formatted with `=` and `;` but that's how it looks when printed to console:

```
 result =     (
    {
 media =             {
        image =                 {
          1000 = "/assets/img/cities/basel-switzerland-1000px.jpg";
          1500 = "/assets/img/cities/basel-switzerland-1500px.jpg";
          250 = "/assets/img/cities/basel-switzerland-250px.jpg";
          500 = "/assets/img/cities/basel-switzerland-500px.jpg";
        };
      };
}
)
```

I've created custom objects but I keep getting a

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

error when I use `[Int: Any]` for the "image" and when I substitute `NSNumber` instead I get an error:

> Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x10ee4ad10) to
>   'NSNumber' (0x10bc88488).

Here is my custom class for the JSON objects:

```
class sampleJSON {
  var mediaDictionary: [String: Any]
  var imageDictionary: [Int: Any]
  var image: URL

  init( mediaDictionary: [String: Any], imageDictionary: [Int: Any], image: URL){
    self.mediaDictionary = mediaDictionary
    self.imageDictionary = imageDictionary
    self.image = image
  }

  init(resultsDictionary:[String: Any]){
    mediaDictionary = (resultsDictionary["media"] as? [String: Any])!
    imageDictionary = (mediaDictionary["image"] as? [Int: Any])!
    image = URL(string: imageDictionary[1000] as! String)!
  }
```

This is how I'm parsing the JSON data:

```
static func downloadAllData(urlExtension: String, completionHandler: @escaping (sampleJSON?) -> ()) {
    let usm = UrlSessionNetworkManager.sharedManager

    if let jsonDictionary = usm.parseJSONFromData(urlExtension:"\(urlExtension)")
    {
      let resultDictionaries = jsonDictionary["result"] as! [[String : Any]]
      for resultsDictionary in resultDictionaries {// enumerate through dictionary
        let nomadInfo = sampleJSON(resultsDictionary: resultsDictionary)

        print(nomadInfo.mediaDictionary)

        completionHandler(nomadInfo)
      }
    } else {
      print("Error: Cannot retrieve JSON Data")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Even though they are "numbers", they are strings because dictionary keys in JSON are strings. You are using a forced downcast, which will throw an exception. Use no downcast and inspect in the the debugger to see what you are *actually* dealing with. Using a forced downcast or force unwrap with data you don't control (ie JSON data from a web server) is asking for a crash. Use conditional casting/unwrapping and handle parse errors more gracefully

Comment: Ok, is that always the case, if it's a dictionary key in JSON no matter what it's always a String?

Comment: What about the key value, can't they be objects other than strings?

Comment: Not in JSON they can't.  See http://www.json.org

Comment: Never use `(a as? b)!`, instead use `a as! b`. I'm looking at `(resultsDictionary["media"] as? [String: Any])!` and `(mediaDictionary["image"] as? [Int: Any])!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all occurences of `[Int: Any]` with `[String: Any]`, and make that change in the server code, too. [As mentioned by @Paulw11, JSON keys can only be strings (but a *value* can be a *string* in double quotes, or a *number*, or **`true`** or **`false`** or **`null`**, or an *object* or an *array*)](http://www.json.org/). Also, as I mentioned, never use `(a as? b)!`, instead use `a as! b`.

The new (and now valid) JSON *should* look like:

```
 result =     (
    {
 media =             {
        image =                 {
          "1000" = "/assets/img/cities/basel-switzerland-1000px.jpg";
          "1500" = "/assets/img/cities/basel-switzerland-1500px.jpg";
          "250" = "/assets/img/cities/basel-switzerland-250px.jpg";
          "500" = "/assets/img/cities/basel-switzerland-500px.jpg";
        };
      };
}
)
```

The custom class should be:

```
class sampleJSON {
  var mediaDictionary: [String: Any]
  var imageDictionary: [String: Any]
  var image: URL

  init( mediaDictionary: [String: Any], imageDictionary: [String: Any], image: URL){
    self.mediaDictionary = mediaDictionary
    self.imageDictionary = imageDictionary
    self.image = image
  }

  init(resultsDictionary:[String: Any]){
    mediaDictionary = resultsDictionary["media"] as! [String: Any]
    imageDictionary = mediaDictionary["image"] as! [String: Any]
    image = URL(string: imageDictionary["1000"] as! String)!
  }
```

And the parsing function should be (just a small, unrelated issue fixed):

```
static func downloadAllData(urlExtension: String, completionHandler: @escaping (sampleJSON?) -> ()) {
    let usm = UrlSessionNetworkManager.sharedManager

    if let jsonDictionary = usm.parseJSONFromData(urlExtension: urlExtension)
    {
      let resultDictionaries = jsonDictionary["result"] as! [[String : Any]]
      for resultsDictionary in resultDictionaries {// enumerate through dictionary
        let nomadInfo = sampleJSON(resultsDictionary: resultsDictionary)

        print(nomadInfo.mediaDictionary)

        completionHandler(nomadInfo)
      }
    } else {
      print("Error: Cannot retrieve JSON Data")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: All of those `!` are crashes waiting to happen. They all need to be dealt with properly.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, I totally agree, but this is better than the old way. It should be done with `guard let x = y else { ... }` statements IMO, but that is up to the asker.